# Why the name of my app doesn't change after update from Mac App Store

Tags: macos, mac-app-store

I have app in App Store with name "App_1". Then I submit app with name "App_2" to update my app with name "App_1". 
When I update App_1.app from Mac App Store the name of my app still "App_1.app" not "App_2.app". Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On apple developers forum I've got answer that's system issue https://devforums.apple.com/thread/142444?tstart=0